# Book on Dynamical Systems

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, chaos-theory

I am a Mathematics undergraduate and want to study about Dynamical Systems. Following are the courses that I have gone through:

1. Logic and Set Theory
2. Real Analysis(Including study of Topology of Metric Spaces)
3. Matrix Theory
4. Combinatorics and Discrete Mathematics
5. Abstract Algebra (Group, Ring and Field Theory)
6. Multivariable Calculus
7. Probability and Statistics
8. Ordinary Differential Equations

**I want to know if I can study Dynamical Systems with these prerequisites** and if so, **please suggest a book** for the same. Moreover, next Semester I will taking courses on Topology, Linear Algebra, Complex Analysis, Partial Differential Equations.

Comment: Strogatz - Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos is worth a read. It is light, and great for building intuition. On the heavier side of things, I've been recommended Guckenheimer and Holmes, but perhaps someone can speak more to that text.

Comment: I recommend the book "A First Course in Chaotic Dynamical Systems" written by Robert L. Devaney to study the basics of dynamical systems. It will surely help you to understand the concepts.